# Sending multiple parts of a Looker dashboard but not all parts in an email scheduled delivery?

Tags: email, visualization, dashboard, looker

LOOKER has the ability to send either the entire dashboard or a single look via eMail to a person.
Currently we want to be able to send either a portion of a dashboard or multiple looks in the same email.

Example we have 4 tiles/looks inside a dashboard but we only want to send 2 of those tiles to a person.

Is it possible to send 2 of those tiles/looks in a single email instead of having to send each tile/look in a separate email?

Within the Dashboard you can set up a schedule:

[image]

But no options show up that allow you to select each tile/look you would like to send so I can only send the entire dashboard in an email.

[image]

Comment: Could you create an additional dashboard with only those 2 looks specifically for emailing?

Comment: @Simeon That would defeat why I want to be able to do what I am asking. I have a Dashboard with over 16 views. I need to break that out into 15 email. Each with the first view and one of the other 15. So having to do it that way I now have to build 15 more dashboards just to be able to send out tailored emails for each.

Comment: I wonder if you split the looks into 15 folders and changed the `see_looks` permissions for each user/folder if they would be able to see them when you email the dashboard https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/access-control-and-permission-management#viewing_data_in_looks_and_dashboards

Comment: @Simeon Do you mean a different folder for each view/look and then build 1 dashboard from all the different looks and then provide permissions to each person on the folders only?